# How to label the outputs of a looping function in alphabetical order in python

Tags: python, loops

I am creating a small program that will first ask how many items you are using, and then let you convert each items weight in grams to pounds. my function currently works but I would like each time it loops to assign the outputs to variables so I can use them in a later function. Here is my current code

```
repeat = int(input("How many Items:"))

for i in range(repeat):
    weight = float(input("What is the weight? "))
    unit = ("pounds")
    pounds = 0.00220462
    converted_weight = float(weight * pounds)
    formatted_float = "{:.2f}".format(converted_weight)

    print(converted_weight)
    print(unit)
```

Comment: You should just accumulate the values into a `list`. Don't try to create additional variables.

Comment: Make lists outside the loop and `append` the calculated values to them. Thanks, @quamrana.

Comment: Accurate variable names are important. I recommend you rename `weight` to `grams`, and `converted_weight` to `pounds`, and prompt for `"What is the weight in grams?"`. Then instead of `pounds`, clarify that it is a **conversion factor** by naming it `pounds_per_gram`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_units

Comment: I will do this, Thank you!

Comment: When you're ready to `import` external packages, you will find that several have nicely addressed this topic area, including https://pypi.org/project/unyt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) which allows you to store a collection of answers.

```
repeat = int(input("How many Items: "))

item_weights = []

for i in range(repeat):
    weight = float(input("What is the weight? "))
    unit = "pounds"
    pounds = 0.00220462
    converted_weight = float(weight * pounds)
    formatted_float = "{:.2f}".format(converted_weight)
    print(formatted_float + ' ' + unit)
    item_weights.append(converted_weight)

# Example of iterating through a list
weight_sum = 0
for weight in item_weights:
    weight_sum += weight

print("Total weight: " + str(weight_sum))

for weight in item_weights:
    # your rest of your code here
    print(weight)
```

Comment: @Strock let me know if this does not do what you are trying to accomplish, I can answer any questions you have about lists or other containers.

Comment: How can I call the list items individually? I will make anoher function (#(singleweight / totalweight) * (total cost * 3) = Individual price) then I would like it to output at the end as 
A = 1.1 lbs - $15.21
B = etc etc

Can I call a this list to accomplish that?

Comment: @Strock I have updated the code to include examples of how to iterate through a list. I recommend you read the Python overview of lists https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

Comment: Thank you, In the second function would I repeat the function with different variables? or make individual functions for each list item?

Comment: I guess what I mean is, would I need to make the function with list[1, 2, 3, 4] etc?

Comment: @Strock I will be honest, I do not really understand your question. When you do a for loop such as `for weight in item_weights`, item_weights is a list of weights (for example the list has 4 weights and they are [100, 200, 150, 175]) and you are going over each item one at a time. You can put all of your "function" inside the for loop, so if you want to make some calculations the "singleweight" is the same as `weight` in the for loop above. I have added a print statement to the for loop so you can see that in each iteration you access a different item in the list.

Comment: I have a separate function that I will use later that calls back specific variables in an equation. How can I call them back in code? So if the weight for the first loop is 1.5 pounds, how can I call back that number in an equation? Where each loop will add another number to a list; how do I make it to where the first time it goes through the second function it first does the first list item, prints the outcome and then does the second function with the 2nd list item etc

Answer (score 0):

I have created a manual version of what I am trying to accomplish and I will open a new discussion requesting assistance with code that can better get my question across @JRose

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).